# how compiler compile template and type checking?? (c++)

Tags: c++, templates

My Question is how compiler compile template and how compiler do type checking.

i wanna know about how compiler compile template code.

first of all, i just show you how i think how template works?

first. compiler copy and paste template code replaced with template argument

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
   T* data;
~~~
};

int main()
{
   vector<int> a;
}

--->

class vector<int>
{
   int* data;
~~~
};

int main()
{
   vector<int> a;
}
```

second. compiler try using this converted code for type checking. ( i think this is why all translation unit using template should have(know) template definition )

this is how i think compiler work.
actually i don't know well about how compiler works.
i just know only abou preprocessing, linker.....

Comment: `vector<int>` has a `int* data` rather than a `T*`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this entire process, and how templates work, should be explained in your C++ textbook. Is there something specific in your textbook's explanation that's unclear to you and you don't understand? If so you should [edit] your question and include a quote of the relevant material from your textbook, with a comment as to what exactly you find to be unclear.

Comment: Read a [good C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), then the [Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science)), then study the source code of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Read also about [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference) and see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i can't understand your word exactly.. sorry im not good at english. maybe you are saying " write exactly what unclear to me about how template works." right? maybe i know how compiler convert template to parameterized template code, but i don't know how compiler do type checking , how compiler know specific template parameter isn't valid.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks for your answer, i have been reading bjarne stroustrup's a tour of c++, maybe this book doen't have about this. so i searched on google. but i couldn't find answer. so i post here. yeah i think that really help me. but i don't have the book now( i'' buy it thank you ), and i don't think i can understand gcc source code now with my knowledge ( i'll do it later!! ). so i post this. just from my curiosity

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks i'll read it

Comment: @hour30000 While the basic idea is simple to understand, a proper understand of how a compiler works is way too complex to be answered in one page. There are many rules like which function overloads are visible. For example, if additionnal overloads become visible between declaration and instanciation point or depending if T is inside a namespace, the compiler needs to know how to handle many edge cases.

Comment: read also some C++ draft standard, e.g. [n4849](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/n4849.pdf). You'll need more than a year full time to understand all details. Try to follow some university courses on compilation, and later contribute to [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or to [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)  - they are open source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are compiled in two phases:

1. At definition time (no instantiation yet) the template code itself is checked for correctness (ignoring template parameters) for example: syntax errors, unknown names, etc.
2. At instantiation time the template code is checked again, for ex. all parts that depend on template parameters are checked.

Note: If you just define a template, but don't use it, then only the 1. phase will be checked.

for example in your case:

```
template <typename T>
class vector
{
   T* data, // 1. Phase check: compile error: missing semicolon
~~~
};

int main()
{
   vector<int> a; // 2. Phase check: Instantiation: T replaced with int and template code rechecked.
}
```